# @DecimalMin is not validating input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, annotations

I have a spring boot project where I try to validate that a numeric input is greater than zero. I used @DecimalMin for that but is not working. I stormed the internet and tried different approaches but none seem to work.

This is the code sample:

```
@GetMapping("/bmi")
public ResponseEntity<BMIDto> getBMI(@RequestParam("mass") @Pattern(regexp = "1-9") @DecimalMin("0") int mass {
    return new .....
}
```

Comment: Please add `)` after `int mass`.

Comment: @Sup19 do you realize that it does not look as here in my ide

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Valid` for request body or field to validate it. Also you can add `@Validated` in controller class.

Comment: This is in controller class, and I try adding Valid then Validated in front of DecimalMin but it did not change anything